# Weird output coming from express' req.query

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm making an `ajax` call to call some node's server side process.

This is my data `object`

```
var data = { 
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2
}
```

and sending the data to the call using `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

When in my `node's route`, `req.query` is as follows:

```
{ '{"field1":"7","field2":"7"}': ''}
```

I can't get to the values using `req.query.field1`, how can I format this output so I can move forward?

Comment: Are you using jquery for ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your request headers not being set properly (content-type:JSON), because you're sending a string.

If you're using jQuery as your post seems to show, you don't need to stringify your data , send it as JSON and jQuery will set the right headers :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/someurl",
  data: { field1: "7", field2: "7" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I need it to be Get, since I want data back after the call. That's ok but if I send it as you suggest, all I get in req.query is { 'object Object': '' }. Any idea?

Comment: besides the POST method, it was all about the headers. Thanks.